# Stat question about Markov Chain

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

An urn contains five red and three green balls. The balls are chosen at random, one by one, from the urn. If a red ball is chosen, it is removed. Any green ball that is chosen is returned to the urn. the selection process continues until all of the red balls have been removed from the urn. What is the mean duration of the game?

Comment: do you have any ideas? There are plenty of solved problems at the bottom of the pagem have a look at them. In short: you need to construct the set of recurrent equations t find the mean first hitting time of some state, which is absorbing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1$ be the number of trials until the first red is removed, let $X_2$ be the number of trials from first removal of a red to the second, and so on up to $X_5$. Then the duration $Y$ of the game is $X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5$, and therefore by the linearity of expectation $E(Y)=\sum_{i=1}^5 E(X_i)$.

Note that $X_1$ has geometric distribution with parameter (probability of success) $p=\frac{5}{8}$. Thus $E(X_1)=\frac{8}{5}$. Similarly, $E(X_2)=\frac{7}{4}$, and so on.